# Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I worked on the tutorial for creating an Google App Engine Application who can communicate with my Android applications via GCM.
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

I also deployed my server application to the Google Cloud. All steps of this tutorial are working, except of the last one. Although I registered my smarthone succesfully on my server application, I cannot send messages to my smartphone. There is the following error message:

```
There was a problem when attempting to send the message using the server
at https://1-dot-fridge1710.appspot.com/_ah/api.
Is your API Key in MessageEndpoint.java (in your App Engine project) set correctly?
Here's the error information:
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401   

com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: HTTP Status Code: 401
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
at de.breckner.fridgemanager.MessageEndpoint.doSendViaGcm(MessageEndpoint.java:170)
at de.breckner.fridgemanager.MessageEndpoint.sendMessage(MessageEndpoint.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I think the problem is the wrong API Key in MessageEndpoint.java. I have tried all of the possibilites, creating an Server API Key, Browser API Key and Android API Key in Google Developers Console, but none of them are working.
Could anybody tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The offical docs says:

**Authentication Error**

The sender account that you're trying to use to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:

```
1. Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
2. Invalid project number sent as key.
3. Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
4. Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.
```

I had same problem a monthn ago and i was using the wrong key in the header.

You're saying that you have tried everything with API KEYS check that you're not committing something from the above mentioned.